# Smarty: How to get value of array in Object

Tags: smarty

I have an array inside an object inside an array in my smarty template. A simplified example below, but using the same structure.

```
Array ( 
    [product] => ModelView Object (
        [model:protected] => Model Object (
            [id] => 1234
        )
    )
)
```

How can I get [id]?

I can get the 'product' object to appear on the page as an array using:

```
$this->get_template_vars('product')
```

But from there I can't seem to narrow it down to only get the [id].

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all it takes is a post on stackoverflow and then you try one more thing after hours and it works.

My solution below.

```
{php}
    $id = $this->get_template_vars('product'); 
    $id = $id->id;
{/php}
```